# customizing the record details page (show page?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm brand new to rails, and have inherited an app I'm trying to make modifications to; it uses activeadmin - which seems nice, but is a bit opaque to me at the moment.

The show page - the page that shows a detailed, single record - doesn't seem to be generated by anything I can find. I found the file dealing with the list of all records, but can't find what's actually generating the details.

I need to add some custom info to this page that's not directly linked to the record in the database itself basically group of related resources.

What file am I looking for? Or do I need to create one somewhere? The listing page is in admin/users.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to edit `admin/users.rb`.

http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-screens.html

The above link documents how to customize the show page.

Comment: ah, thank you so much. a lot of rails feels like 'magic' -- sticking my toe in the water is a bit frightening at the moment.